How to perform git operations behind a proxy without local authentication credentials?
I would like to access a private git repository without having git authentication credentials available on my local machine.
In my current setup, users have root access to a machine with git ssh keys stored directly on the machine, and would like to prevent users from having access to the keys.
Ideally, git functionality would remain the same and git authentication would happen behind a proxy which my machine has secure access to (without obviously allowing users to access the keys on the proxy).
I've looked into several other posts about git proxy:

Accessing a git repository via ssh behind a firewall
https://gist.github.com/ozbillwang/005bd1dfc597a2f3a00148834ad3e551

but these seem to require auth to be present on the local machine.

I'm not sure I got that. You have multiple users who have ssh access to some machine which, in turn, have git repo properly setup to push and fetch from a github repo. And you want these users to use the git repo on that machine to commit and fetch changes. Is this is the use case?

The machine is set up with an ssh key that is authorized to read/write to a git server. I want users to continue to be able to run git operations on that host, but prevent them from viewing the key and potentially copying it elsewhere.

why not use ssh jail?

If you are using GitHub for git repo then you can leverage the GitHub Token feature to authenticate with GitHub.
Check out the article below for reference:
https://kettan007.medium.com/how-to-clone-a-git-repository-using-personal-access-token-a-step-by-step-guide-ab7b54d4ef83

I don't see how this obfuscates the authentication from the end user - wouldn't the users need the PAT on the original host machine to perform this type of auth?
